# offset long series labels with lines

Tags: highcharts

is this possible to offset labels on a bubble chart using little pointer lines, like on this screenshot:

[image]

my labels are quite long, this is why I would need to offset them, so that they do not appear in the center of the bubble

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use annotations with connector shape type.

```
  annotations: [{
    labelOptions: {
      shape: 'connector',
      ...,
    },
    labels: [{
      point: 'BE',
      y: -80
    }, ...]
  }]
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/58xrhuvz/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/annotations

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/advanced-chart-features/annotations-module